# Is there a way to re-create all the migrations for a Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to re-create all the migrations for a Rails 3 application from the models or schema file?

Comment: Nope. Those files have no knowledge of what your migrations were. That would be like asking if you know the names of two cities, you could reconstruct the route you took to get from one to the other.

Comment: @Gurdipe why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't "re-create" migrations if you didn't keep them under source control. However, you can dump the current schema to Ruby with:

```
# create db/schema.rb
rake db:schema:dump
```

or to SQL with:

```
# create db/structure.sql
rake db:structure:dump
```

This will enable you to recreate the *current* structure of the database on demand, but your historical migrations are still lost unless you kept them under source control or backed them up somewhere.